# Firefox 122.0.1 ignores sound settings on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Tags: sound, firefox, headphones

As the title says, Firefox 122.0.1 will always ignore my sound settings on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS.

If I have my headphones connected, in Chrome I can change the output device in the Ubuntu sound settings from the headphones (default) to the screen and this will result in hearing Chrome through the screen.

However, this will not work properly in Firefox.

Comment: Does moving Firefox to the desired output device in `pavucontrol` work?

Comment: After installing `pavucontrol` and switching Firefox to the desired output device, now I can even control it from Ubuntu's default sound panel and it switches correctly. Thanks Daniel!

Answer (score 1):

Moving Firefox to the desired output device in `pavucontrol` works. I can even control it from Ubuntu's default sound panel and it switches correctly now.

Comment: Please don't link comments, they are frequently deleted.